# On closing Dialog box the screen flickers due to scrollbar which appears on right.What should I do to hide it?

Tags: sapui5

[image]

[image]

On IE11, while selecting any element from the dialog or on clicking Cancel Button, the scrollbar appears for some milliseconds due to which screen flickers from right to left and back.
Any solution for this?

[!Dialogue Box[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aecr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aecr.png)

[!Scroll at right side of screen while closing Dialogue box[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbTx9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbTx9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue no-longer exists in the later versions of UI5